# Jquery - dynamic calculation

Tags: jquery

I am trying to create JS to perform a dynamic calculation.  But, it does not work (does nothing when put a number in INPUT "qtyoriginal". Am I missing something?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function price() {
    var _qtyoriginal = document.getElementById(qtyoriginal).value;
    var _qtyjunior = document.getElementById(qtyjunior).value; 
    (priceOriginal).value = 46.5 * _qtyoriginal;
    document.getElementById(priceTotal).value = 8.5 + 43.5 * _qtyjunior + 46.5 * _qtyoriginal;
}
</script>
```

HTML

```
<td class="center"><input type="text" id="qtyoriginal" name="qtyoriginal" 
class="number validate[custom[integer]]" value="" autofocus style="text-align:right;" 
placeholder="0" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = '0'" 
onChange="price()"/></td>
<td class="center">46.50</td>
<td id="priceOriginal" name="priceOriginal" class="right">0.00</td>
```

Comment: Should be as simple as not adding two versions of jQuery to the same site, the code you have should work in jQuery 1.9

Comment: HTML (abbreviation):
    <td class="center"><input type="text" id="qtyoriginal" name="qtyoriginal" class="number validate[custom[integer]]" value="" autofocus style="text-align:right;" placeholder="0" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = '0'" /></td>
    <td class="center">46.50</td>
    <td id="priceOriginal" name="priceOriginal" class="right">0.00</td>
<td id="priceTotal" name="priceTotal" class="right">0.00</td>

Comment: Take the time to rewrite it so you only have one version of jQuery. You will probably find that solves it.

Comment: Yes, logically has to work on a later version. Also, tried to check if a least a simple js will work, but it did not. Like : <script type="text/javascript">
  var _qtyoriginal = document.getElementById('qtyoriginal');
  var _priceOriginal = document.getElementById('priceOriginal');

  _qtyoriginal.onblur = function(){
    _priceOriginal.value = (_qtyoriginal* 46.5);
  };

Comment: Here is the simplest code that has to do the same, but it does not work: function price() {
  var _qtyoriginal = document.getElementById(qtyoriginal).value;
  var _qtyjunior = document.getElementById(qtyjunior).value; 
  document.getElementById(priceOriginal).value = 46.5*_qtyoriginal;
  document.getElementById(priceJunior).value = 43.5*_qtyjunior;
  document.getElementById(priceTotal).value = 8.5 + 43.5*_qtyjunior + 46.5*_qtyoriginal;

Comment: **INDENT YOUR CODE** to massively increase the readability ....

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Since you are using the Jquery then why you are not using the jquery syntax in all of your code? 
instad of using `document.getElementById(id)`, you can use `$("#id")`.

And see below fix to your method:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function price() {
            var _qtyoriginal = $("#qtyoriginal").val();
            var _qtyjunior = $("#qtyjunior").val(); 
            var result = 46.5 * _qtyoriginal; 
            $("#priceOriginal").text(result);
            result = 8.5 + 43.5 * _qtyjunior + 46.5 * _qtyoriginal; 
            $("#priceTotal").text(result);
        }
        </script>
```

Note that I am not sure what is the component type of priceTotal, But if it is an input then to enter a value to it user `.val(newValue);` if it is not use `.text(newValue)` or `.html(newValue)`

Read more:

1. http://api.jquery.com/val/
2. http://api.jquery.com/text/
3. https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/